# Boost.DI can we use a factory method instead of a constructor, without needing manual wiring of dependencies?

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

In the code base I am working with, we heavily use shared_ptr and weak_ptr.
It is common for an object to contain a weak_ptr to itself, then hand that off to other objects.

I really hate std::shared_from_this...

1. It doesn't work if the object is not owned by a shared pointer (someone creates the object on the stack, for example.. or, just plain old new).
2. Its doesn't work if you call this->shared_from_this() before the constructor has returned... and, we tend to do all the setup in the contructor (RAII) which will often need the weak self pointer.

I've found it just creates problems, especially for the junior devs..

The solution I have been using, looks a little like this...

```cpp
class MyThing : public IThing {
    MyThing(/* dependencies */) { /* leave me empty, put init in New() */ }
    std::weak_ptr<MyThing> wthis;
public:
   static std::shared_ptr<MyThing> New(/* dependencies */) {
      // create object, assigm members, but run no code.
      auto o = std::shared_ptr<MyThing>(new MyThing(/* dependencies */));
      // initialise weak self pointer.
      o->wthis = o;
      
      o->DoConstructorStuff();
      return o
   }
};
```

The private constructor forces you to use a factory method, the factory method sets up the weak_ptr first... now, its always safe to use.. and I find people don't run into problems of crashes, because some code path tried to use weak-this too soon... Also, the object is fully constructed when New returns..

The problem I'm having, is that Boost.DI seems to really, really, really want to use Constructors..

At the moment, I'm having to bind using lambdas...
But this means, I'm missing out on the automatic dependency resolution..

```cpp
auto di = boost::di::make_injector(
  boost::di::bind<IThing>().to([](const auto & injector) {
    return MyThing::New(
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency0>>(),
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency1>>(),
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency2>>(),
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency3>>(),
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency4>>(),
        injector.template create<std::shared_ptr<ThingDependency5>>(),
    );
  })
);
```

What can I do to improve this?
I don't want to be repeating myself (declaring dependencies inside the factory method, AND inside the di binding.

Comment: "we tend to do all the setup in the contructor (RAII) which will often need the weak self pointer" - that seems like the code smell: it really looks like an over-reliance on weak pointers where you need none. Often, by extension this indicates over-use of shared_ptr in the first place. If it's about "self-registering" consider more inversion of control (DI is that, after all) and make the "registration facility" create the instance while registering it.

Comment: @sehe yes, you are right... the code absolutely stinks...  however.. it is what it is.. and im trying to improve it in baby steps..   am at the stage, where i would like to introduce DI, and i would rather not have to re-factor the legacy code first... its a HUGE codebase

Comment: I feel that. I appreciate the energy towards improving legacy code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `enable_shared_from_this` idiom which is exactly this, but [standard and portable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). In fact `std::make_shared` as well as `shared_ptr<>` constructors do **exactly** what you require the factory for:

> the factory method sets up the weak_ptr first... now, its always safe to use..

From a quick scan through the [DI examples](https://boost-ext.github.io/di/examples.html) it seems like shared_ptr is already fully supported, so once you pair it up with `enabe_shared_from_this` you should have everything you need.

Comment: perhaps i didn't explain very well.. or perhaps i misunderstood your answer...
?

the function shared_from_this() throws an exception, if called in the constructor...  and I need access to the shared_ptr to the Object at construction time.  I want to fully construct the object inside the constructor... and a fully constructed object has a weak self reference.

Comment: It's quiite contradictory to say "I want to fully construct the object inside the constructor" and spend the rest of the time explaining how you **must** use a factory function and 2-phase initialization instead. Perhaps you can show a minimal, self-contained example and we can be concrete about your use case. I find the Boost.DI examples to be pretty inscrutable (e.g. my brain stopped functioning after reading an unexplained `//<<define injector>>
    auto module = [] { return di::make_injector(di::bind<>().to(123)); };`) but I'm usually able to check working code.

Comment: Thanks @sehe, what i should have said then... is i want the object to be fully constructed by the time the caller has access to it, Yes, my solution is 2 phase, but at least the author of the class is doing the two phases, rather the consumer needing to know they have to call an extra setup function.  the lambda bindings in boost.di are quite clumsy.. but, if i need them, i need them :).. Ill hang about and see is a Boost.DI expert pops up before accepting the answer.